# Retrieving subset of a data frame by finding entries with NA in specific columns

Tags: r, subset

Suppose we had a data frame with `NA` values like so,

```
>data
A  B  C  D
1  3  NA 4
2  1  3  4
NA 3  3  5
4  2  NA NA
2  NA 4  3
1  1  1  2
```

I wish to know a general method for retrieving the subset of `data` with `NA` values in `C` or `A`. So the output should be,

```
A  B  C  D
1  3  NA 4
NA 3  3  5
4  2  NA NA
```

I tried using the subset command like so, `subset(data, A==NA | C==NA)`, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Comparing A==NA always returns FALSE. That's intentional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
# Read your data
data <- read.table(text="
A  B  C  D
1  3  NA 4
2  1  3  4
NA 3  3  5
4  2  NA NA
2  NA 4  3
1  1  1  2",header=T,sep="")

# Now subset your data 
subset(data, is.na(C) | is.na(A))
   A B  C  D
1  1 3 NA  4
3 NA 3  3  5
4  4 2 NA NA
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! And its easy to remember, and easy to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

A very handy function for these sort of things is `complete.cases`. It checks row-wise for `NA` and if any returns FALSE. If there are no NAs, returns TRUE.

So, you need to subset just the two columns of your data and then use `complete.cases(.)` and `negate` it and subset those rows back from your original data, as follows:

```
# assuming your data is in 'df'
df[!complete.cases(df[, c("A", "C")]), ]
#    A B  C  D
# 1  1 3 NA  4
# 3 NA 3  3  5
# 4  4 2 NA NA
```